# Help with group by clause in projection queries

Tags: c#, nhibernate, group-by, nhibernate-projections

I want to group records of people coming in on any airport per day per hour. So basically I want a count of people coming in everyhour at any particular airport. Below is my code for it.

```
string ArrDate = 
                String.Format("LTRIM(STR(MONTH({0}))) + '/' + LTRIM(STR(DAY({0}))) + '/' + LTRIM(STR(YEAR({0})))", "DestinationDatetime");

            string ArrTime=
                String.Format("rtrim(datepart(hh, DestinationDatetime)) +' Hour'", "DestinationDatetime");

            Template.Criteria.
                SetProjection(
                        Projections.ProjectionList()
                        .Add(Projections.Count("ID"), "ACount")
                        .Add(Projections.SqlGroupProjection(ArrDate  + " as DateVal", ArrDate 
                                new string[] { "DateVal" }, new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.String }))
                        .Add(Projections.SqlGroupProjection(ArrTime + " as TimeVal", ArrTime,
                                new string[] { "TimeVal" }, new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.String }))
                        .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Airport"), "APort"));

            Template.Criteria.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToEntityMap);
```

Now, the above query gives me records in the below manner,

```
Date   Airport  Time      Count
 12/16  ORD     13 Hour     5
 12/16  ORD     17 Hour     6
 12/16  MWK     10 Hour     7
```

I want the query to display the records as,

```
  Date   Airport  Time      Count
   12/16  ORD      1 pm        5
                   4pm         6
          MWK      10 am       7
```

So that the date and airport do not keep repeating themselves. I want to have count of people coming in after every hour.i.e., between 1-2am, 2-3am and so on..

Comment: Why not manipulate the data after the fact? This doesn't seem like an nhibernate problem.

Comment: I know but because there are a lot of airports, I thought if there was a way around with using projection queries maybe that would simplify things a bit..

Answer (score 1):

Even if nHibernate can do this for you this is most definitely not a database concern this is a presentation concern. You will need to add some logic in the presentation that ignores duplicate dates.

Is this a asp.net, asp.net MVC, WPF or winforms project?

Comment: oh, can;t help you with the dedups as WPF is not my thing, you may want to ask a new question here on stack overflow which asks how you go about supressing repeating rows of data.